# Python: how to count the access of an instance variable

Tags: python, class

I have a python class as below.

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self, logger):
       self.b = B()
       self.logger = logger
   def meth1(self):
       self.b.mymethod1()
   def meth2(self):
       self.meth1()
       self.b.mymethod2()
   .........
class B(object):
   ---------
```

How can I count how many time I accessed self.b variable on the invocation of meth2() or any method of class A. Is there any way, I can log the usage of self.b variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to make a property, you can log the read/write access using `__getattribute__` (not `__getattr__` since `b` exists and would not be called) and `__setattr__`:

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self):
       # initialize counters first !
       self.b_read_counter = 0
       self.b_write_counter = 0
       # initialize b
       self.b = 12

   def __getattribute__(self,attrib):
      # log read usage
      if attrib=="b":
          self.b_read_counter+=1
      # now return b value
      return object.__getattribute__(self, attrib)

   def __setattr__(self,attrib,value):
      if attrib=="b":
          self.b_write_counter+=1

      return object.__setattr__(self, attrib,value)

a = A()

a.b = 23    # second write access (first is in the init method)
if a.b == 34:  # first read access
    print("OK")
if a.b == 34:
    print("OK")
if a.b == 34:  # third read access
    print("OK")
print(a.b_read_counter)
print(a.b_write_counter)
```

result:

```
3
2
```

Comment: Thanks.. this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

make 'b' a property and and increase the counter corresponding to be in the setter.

```
@property
def b(self):
  self.b_counter += 1
  return self._b
```

and in your class replace b with _b

Answer (score 1):

You can use [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) for this or just make a property which is basically is descriptor.

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(self, logger):
       self._b = B()
       self._b_counter = 0
       self.logger = logger

   @property
   def b(self):
       self._b_counter += 1
       return self._b

   def meth1(self):
       self.b.mymethod1()

   def meth2(self):
       self.meth1()
       self.b.mymethod2()
```

Comment: Using property is a good idea, still I will go with getattribute answer, since it can handle both instance variable and instance method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use property, somtehing like:

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, logger):
      self._b = B()
      self._count = 0
      self.logger = logger

  @property
  def b(self):
     self._count += 1
     return self._b
  ...
  ...
```